# How to handle time difference for expiry dates?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, timezone

I am working on a Web API project that will be used by clients in different time zones.

Say our server will be in the US and the users can access the service anywhere.

When we create a user we have to set the expiry date.

```
 public DateTime ExpireOn { get; set; }
```

And from client and posting the date like this

```
{
 "expireOn":"2020-12-30"
}
```

And when I am checking the expire date am doing like this

```
if(user.ExpireOn >= DateTime.UtcNow)
{
return true;
}
```

Now the problem what if I create the user from outside of the US.

Suggest me how to handle the expiry in a proper way.

> Is there any standard way of for handling expiry dates for users in different time zones?
>   Here is the blog explaining times zones to display in the user time offset http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/9/how_to_display_dates_and_times_in_clients_timezone

Comment: You should post the data as UTC, not as local timestamp.

Comment: The other answers suggesting UTC are not necessarily correct.  You need to ask yourself - what do YOU mean by that date?  End of that day in UTC?  In the time zone of your business?  In the user's time zone?  Some other time zone?  Only you can answer that.  The solution varies depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enforce the usage of UTC timezone (Coordinated Universal Time) for calling your API.

I'd also suggest using an standard such as ISO 8601.

Answer (score 0):

Using Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) to send data from the API will ensure that the dates are unaffected by time zones

You can get the UTC date in JavaScript like this:

```
var myDate = new Date(); // Set this to your date in whichever timezone.
var utcDate = myDate.toUTCString();
```

Comment: Except that parsing strings with the Date constructor is not a good idea. Much better to parse them manually, a library can help but if a single format is used then a 2 line function will suffice.